# What part of speech is this prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, parts-of-speech

What part of speech does "into a gourmet meal" function as in this sentence:

> > "Watch this iron chef turn instant noodles into a gourmet meal"

Comment: A prepositional phrase is just that. That is the part of speech. However, you can also say: turn into is a phrasal verb and gourmet meal is a direct object.

Comment: It's a preposition phrase headed by the preposition "into". The structure of "turn instant noodles into a gourmet meal" is: verb - Od - [prep+O], the latter constituent being a complement of "turn".

Comment: @BillJ is a preposition phrase a complement of noodles?

Comment: No; It's a complement of "turn". "Instant noodles into a gourmet meal" is not a syntactic unit, not a constituent.